# HttpContext.Current.Session["id"] != null)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class to check if a user is logged in a mvc 4 web site.

But after a few calls I get the following error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

The piece of code that is causing the error is: **HttpContext.Current.Session["id"] != null)**

```
using System.Web;


namespace mywebsite.BObjects
{
    public class SecurityManagement
    {
        public bool IsAuthenticatedWithActiveSession()
        {            
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.Session["id"] != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I use a razor view to check if the user is logged in

```
 @{
                        SecurityManagement verify = new SecurityManagement();

                        if (verify.IsAuthenticatedWithActiveSession())
                    {
                        <a href="@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")">Log Out</a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")">Login</a>
                    }          
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just had to remove the Session name:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.Session != null) { return true; } else { return false; }
```